# HXT xpickle (de)serialising between attribute values and value constructors

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I'm trying to write an xpickle which serialises the value constructors of some type into XML attribute values of a specific attribute and de-serialises the XML attribute values back into value constructors of the type.

I have the follow data:

```
module Main where

import Text.XML.HXT.Core

newtype Things = Things [Thing]
data Thing = Thing (Maybe Property)
data Property = A | B

someThings :: Things
someThings = Things [ Thing (Just A)
                    , Thing Nothing
                    , Thing (Just B)
                    ]
```

And I'd like to serialise this into something like:

```
<things>
  <thing property="a" />
  <thing />
  <thing property="b" />
</things>
```

Here's the approach I'm taking:

```
instance XmlPickler Things where
  xpickle = xpWrap ( \things -> Things things , \(Things things) -> things ) $
            xpElem "things" $
            xpThings

xpThings :: PU [Thing]
xpThings = xpList xpickle

instance XmlPickler Thing where
  xpickle = xpElem "thing" $
            xpWrap ( \p -> Thing p , \(Thing p) -> p ) $
            xpProperty

xpProperty :: PU (Maybe Property)
xpProperty = xpOption $ xpAttr "property" xpPropertyValue

xpPropertyValue :: PU Property
xpPropertyValue = xpAlt tag ps
  where
    tag A = 1
    tag B = 2
    ps = [ xpTextAttr "a"
         , xpTextAttr "b"
         ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ showPickled [ withIndent yes ] someThings
  return ()
```

Here, `xpProperty` creates or reads an `@property` attribute and then uses `xpPropertyValue` to work out the value. `xpPropertyValue` determines the value depending on the value constructor of the value: `A` gives `"a"` and `B` gives `"b"` and the values are constructed using the `xpTextAttr` function. The problem here is that `xpTextAttr` is `String -> PU String` and I'm trying to use it where I need a `PU Property`. But I can't work out an alternative way of generating a `PU Property` value that's dependent on the value constructor of a `Property` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't using `xpTextAttr` correctly. First of all its first parameter should be the attribute name `"property"` and secondly, it returns the text it matches.

You want to return the constructor `A` or `B` respectively.

You need to use `xpWrap` to specify the mapping (both ways) between the text contents of the property (`"a"` or `"b"`) and those constructors. And the tags are 0-based I believe, so 0 and 1.

```
where
  tag A = 0
  tag B = 1
  ps = [ xpWrap (const A,const "a") $ xpTextAttr "property"
       , xpWrap (const B,const "b") $ xpTextAttr "property"
       ]
```

Then the call to `xpAttr` is wrong. Honestly I'm not sure what `xpAttr` is for, something to do with qualified names. In fact sufficient code for `xpProperty` is

```
xpProperty :: PU (Maybe Property)
xpProperty = xpOption $ xpPropertyValue
```

Comment: It seems that there's no `Functor` instance for `PU`. When you compile this you get: `No instance for (Functor PU) arising from a use of ‘<$’`. I don't know what an `fmap` implementation for `PU` would do.

Comment: Ah yes, because it's constructing a reversible parser to go from `PU String` to `PU Property` requires two functions, one each way. Try `xpWrap (const A) (const "a") $ xpTextAttr "a`

Comment: Still haven't cracked this: giving the list argument to `xpAlt` as `[ xpWrap ( const A, const "a" ) $ xpTextAttr "a" , ... ]` results in serialising to `<thing property="" />` and an `xpCheckEmptyAttributes: unprocessed XML attribute(s) detected` error on de-serialising.

Comment: Ah. That is the right way to use `xpWrap` now but it was the wrong way to use `xpTextAttr` and `xpAttr`. In fact you don't want to use `xpAttr` at all here, you just want to use `xpTextAttr` with first parameter being "property" and second parameter being the pickler for the actual text.

Comment: Oh, also, the tags should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 2!